# Problem with initializing a type with WinsdorContainer

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

```
    public ApplicationView(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string configFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "log4net.config");
        FileInfo configFileInfo = new FileInfo(configFilePath);
        XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(configFileInfo);

        IConfigurationSource configSource = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ActiveRecord") as IConfigurationSource;
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Danel.Nursing.Model");
        ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(assembly, configSource);         

        WindsorContainer windsorContainer = ApplicationUtils.GetWindsorContainer();
        windsorContainer.Kernel.AddComponentInstance<ApplicationView>(this);
        windsorContainer.Kernel.AddComponent(typeof(ApplicationController).Name, typeof(ApplicationController));
        controller = windsorContainer.Resolve<ApplicationController>(); // exception is thrown here

        OnApplicationLoad(args);
    }
```

The stack trace is this:

> Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException
>   was unhandled
>   Message="ComponentActivator: could not
>   instantiate
>   Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions.DataServices.NurseAbsenceDataService"
>   Source="Castle.MicroKernel"
>   StackTrace:
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstance(CreationContext
>   context, Object[] arguments, Type[]
>   signature)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveServiceDependency(CreationContext
>   context, ComponentModel model,
>   DependencyModel dependency)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context, ISubDependencyResolver
>   parentResolver, ComponentModel model,
>   DependencyModel dependency)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateConstructorArguments(ConstructorCandidate
>   constructor, CreationContext context,
>   Type[]& signature)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveServiceDependency(CreationContext
>   context, ComponentModel model,
>   DependencyModel dependency)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context, ISubDependencyResolver
>   parentResolver, ComponentModel model,
>   DependencyModel dependency)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateConstructorArguments(ConstructorCandidate
>   constructor, CreationContext context,
>   Type[]& signature)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveServiceDependency(CreationContext
>   context, ComponentModel model,
>   DependencyModel dependency)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context, ISubDependencyResolver
>   parentResolver, ComponentModel model,
>   DependencyModel dependency)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateConstructorArguments(ConstructorCandidate
>   constructor, CreationContext context,
>   Type[]& signature)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler
>   handler, Type service, IDictionary
>   additionalArguments)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler
>   handler, Type service)
>          at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.get_Item(Type
>   service)
>          at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve(Type
>   service)
>          at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.ResolveT
>          at Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.ApplicationView..ctor(String[]
>   args) in
>   E:\Agile\Scheduling\Danel.Nursing.Scheduling\ApplicationView.cs:line
>   65
>          at Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in
>   E:\Agile\Scheduling\Danel.Nursing.Scheduling\Program.cs:line
>   24
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:
>   System.ArgumentNullException
>          Message="Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: types"
>          Source="mscorlib"
>          ParamName="types"
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type[]
>   types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
>               at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.FastCreateInstance(Type
>   implType, Object[] arguments, Type[]
>   signature)
>               at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstance(CreationContext
>   context, Object[] arguments, Type[]
>   signature)
>          InnerException:

It actually says that the type that I'm trying to initialize does not exist, I think.
This is the concreate type that it complains about:

```
   namespace Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions.DataServices
    {
        using System;
        using Helpers;
        using Rhino.Commons;
        using Danel.Nursing.Model;
        using NHibernate.Expressions;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using DateUtil = Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions.Helpers.DateUtil;
        using Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions.DataServices.Interfaces;

        public class NurseAbsenceDataService : AbstractDataService<NurseAbsence>, INurseAbsenceDataService
        {
            NurseAbsenceDataService(IRepository<NurseAbsence> repository)
                : base(repository)
            {
            }

            //...
        }
    }
```

The AbstractDataService only holds the IRepository for now.
Anyone got an idea why the exception is thrown?

EDIT:
The problem lays here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions.Interfaces;
using Rhino.Commons;
using System.Reflection;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions.Helpers
{
    public class DataServicesInitiator : IDataServicesInitiator
    {
        public void AddToIocContainer(ref WindsorContainer windsorContainer)
        {
            if (windsorContainer.Kernel.HasComponent(typeof(IRepository<>)) == false)
                windsorContainer.AddComponent(typeof(ARRepository<>).FullName, typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(ARRepository<>));
            foreach (Type type in Assembly.Load("Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions").GetTypes())
            {
                if (type == null)
                    continue;

                if (type.Namespace != "Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions.DataServices")
                    continue;

                if (type.IsAbstract || type.IsInterface)
                    continue;

                if (windsorContainer.Kernel.HasComponent(type.FullName))
                    continue;

                if (type.GetInterfaces().Length == 0)
                    windsorContainer.AddComponent(type.FullName, type);
                else
                    windsorContainer.AddComponent(type.FullName, type.GetInterfaces()[0], type);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason type is null although GetTypes return no null types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the inner exception say? It looks like the constructor for the type threw an exception or it was unable to properly call the constructor for some other reason...

### Update

You can get everything - ActiveRecord, Windsor with MicroKernel, DynamicProxy and NHibernate 
by downloading [ActiveRecord package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/ActiveRecord/2.1/AR%202.1.2.zip/download). It's all there.

If you **don't** want to update you may take alternative approach - write a custom Activator for this component (inherit from the default one and override the method which exposes the bug.)
This should be the safest workaround.

Comment: NullArgumentException: types parameter is null

Comment: The last version (don't know about previous ones) does explicit check for null and initializes the parameter before calling the `type.GetConstructor` which is what I believe is causing the exception in your case. So I reckon you have some old version.

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic: Edited. Please take a look

Comment: Current version of Windsor is 2.1, and 2.5 is just round the corner. I really suggest you to upgrade.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this outside of Windsor?

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic: Upgrading it breaks my project completely.
What do you mean outside of Windsor?

Comment: By outside of Windsor I mean can you reproduce the issues w/o using Windsor.

I'd suggest you to take the time to upgrade to later version where I'm pretty sure the issue does not exist

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic: I have no idea how to start reproducing it w/o using Windsor. What exactly do you mean? If I don't add it to the WindsorContainer I get another exception. 'Waiting for dependencies'

Comment: ok, scratch it. It makes more sense for you to update to later version of Windsor and the problem should go away.

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic: Is there no easy fix here? Upgrading might take a week.

Comment: Honestly I don't know. Like you said it's very bizarre, and I don't really know how to help you, since I don't know the real cause of this.

There's a massive number of updates The version you have is 3 years old, and there were two big releases in the meantime and another is approaching.

I haven't seen RC3 version for a while, but there weren't too many breaking changes so update should be pretty straightforward. Shoot me an email if you need any assistance with it.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer although I got almost none. I will contact you through your blog. I'm saying I will have problems since ActiveRecord apearently depeands on MicroKernel which is upgraded as well. And then I have to upgrade it and NHibernate with many many breaking changes.

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic: Email sent :/

Comment: Updating breaks my code and it will take weeks to fix it. What do you mean write an Activator and expose the bug?

Comment: I mean, since the bug is in `DefaultComponentActivator` then swap the activator for your own implementation that does not have the bug.